# Trying to insert a table into jinja2 template from flask

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I have been trying to create my first Flask website, using super simple templates in `Jinja2`. *(I started with my regular html and abandoned it quickly because figuring out where to put things was a nightmare. I will go back in after this hard part and tweak the flask code, for now, I have eliminated EVERYTHING but the html declaration and the attempt at dropping in the table.)*

**Flask Code:**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
import redis
from flask import json
from dateutils.parser import parse
from flask_table import Table, Col, DatetimeCol
r=redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port =6379, db=0)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/p/')
def p():
    raw = r.get('rData')
    raw= yaml.load(raw)
    raw = json.loads(raw)
    for item in raw:
         item['date_time'] = parse(item['date_time'])
    class ItemTable(Table):
        Sensor = Col("Sensor")
        date_time = DatetimeCol("Date & Time")
        Reading = Col("Reading")
    table = ItemTable(raw)
    return render_template('p.html'), table

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

This code will call the page /p/ locally and *if i ask it to show* `raw` it will print out the data for this table (which I have included below).

`{{ raw }}`

I get my dictionary back!

But when I try to show the table that 
`ItemTable` should create, it crashes my page or nothing shows at all. I have also tried using the return code this way:

```
        return render_template('p.html', table=table)
```

passing it as a variable of fully executed html, nothing good comes of it.
`{{ table }}`

**Actual Data in a list of dictionaries:**

```
[{"date_time": "2016-08-03T14:00:00.000-04:00", "Reading": 27.5, "Sensor": "Water Temperature (degrees Celsius)"}, {"date_time": "2016-08-03T14:00:00.000-04:00", "Reading": 0.91, "Sensor": "Lake Gage Height (in feet)"}, {"date_time": "2016-08-03T14:00:00.000-04:00", "Reading": 53.0, "Sensor": "Specific Conductivity in microSiemens"}, {"date_time": "2016-08-03T14:00:00.000-04:00", "Reading": 7.3, "Sensor": "Dissolved Oxygen (ppm)"}, {"date_time": "2016-08-03T14:00:00.000-04:00", "Reading": 6.9, "Sensor": "pH (standard field)"}, {"date_time": "2016-08-03T14:00:00.000-04:00", "Reading": 27.7, "Sensor": "Air Temperature (in degrees Celsius)"}, {"date_time": "2016-08-03T14:00:00.000-04:00", "Reading": 2.5, "Sensor": "Wind Speed (in mph)"}, {"date_time": "2016-08-03T14:00:00.000-04:00", "Reading": 238.0, "Sensor": "Wind Direction (degrees CW from North)"}, {"Reading": 30.7, "Sensor": "Relative Humidity", "date-Time": "2016-08-03T14:00:00.000-04:00"}, {"date_time": "2016-08-03T14:00:00.000-04:00", "Reading": 1.26, "Sensor": "Marsh Gage Height in feet"}, {"date_time": "2016-08-03T14:00:00.000-04:00", "Reading": 0.01, "Sensor": "24 Cumulative Precipication (inches)"}]
```

I pull this out of a redis cache I created, but you can just set `raw=` to the above list and substitute it.

**Conundrum:**

What do I need to insert in the Jinja2 to make the table show up from one of these two `return` presentations, or is there some other way to tell flask to port the converted list of dictionaries to the template?

I have searched everywhere and the page on flask-table does not show how to present it on the other side.

My goal is to drop it in a container that is a child to the base layout. but just getting it to show up as a table is enough, I can figure the rest out from there.

**Simplest HTML/Jinja template I could create:**

```
<!doctype html>

<h1> test </h1>


{{table}}
```

I tried using `{% table %}` also to no avail.

I am not sure if the problem is that I generated html in flask and tried to send it to the template or if I am not telling Jinja how to present this `table` element that I have created and included with the `render_template` method.

the `<h1> test </h1>` is just to allow me to see if the page is rendering at all when I send the table. It is not important.

I believe the problem that I am having is that most tutorials are over simplified and each set of documentation (`Flask` & `Jinja2`) are light on what happens on the other side of the equation. I found **ONE** explanation of `flask-table` presented on two pages but the same stuff. Neither made a suggestion about calling it with a template.

Update:

I am getting a KeyError when I run it now: the changes are as follows:

```
    raw= yaml.load(raw) #new to make a list for reading after next line
    raw = json.loads(raw) #makes it iterable in UTF-8
    for item in raw:
         item['date_time'] = parse(item['date_time']) #creates dates but throws 
    errors which stops flask
```

New Edit: Part of the Data after json.loads:

```
 [{u'Reading': 25.9,
  u'Sensor': u'Water Temperature (degrees Celsius)',
  u'date_time': u'2016-08-05T08:45:00.000-04:00'},
 {u'Reading': 0.88,
  u'Sensor': u'Lake Gage Height (in feet)',
  u'date_time': u'2016-08-05T08:45:00.000-04:00'}]
```

Data After `parse['date_time']:

```
raw[1]['date_time']
datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 5, 8, 45, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -14400))
```

**New Update:** I somehow missed a capital **T** in the `date_time` field, so correcting that fixed the KeyError...but I still cannot get it to pass over into the HTML. I get a whole bunch of lines referring to the folders and files, then I get:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'datetime_formats'
```

Why are dates and times so much fun?

Comment: looks like LC_TIME in your locale not configured

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert timestamps to datetime objects

```
from dateutil.parser import parse # pip install python-dateutil

raw = json.loads(raw)
for item in raw:
    item['date_time'] = parse(item['date_time'])
```

And pass `table` to template

```
return render_template('p.html', table=table)
```

Upd: All items must have a `date_time` key. Some items in your example have `date-Time` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that in a bit and see how it goes. I am working with DEBUG on, but it is still super hard to figure out where the problems are. It is crazy that the problem is the format of the content.

Comment: I have  tried that method and it still does not work. I had to add a line of code to coerce the data into a list to iterate through: `raw = yaml.load(raw)`  , before the  `json.loads`  and then I added your line. I can make it convert the data in iPython notebook, but it throws a KeyError flag and in flask the error kills the rendering.

Comment: that is the whole message KeyError. When I look at the data it shows the date converted. I think that python does not like the format of the data after it is parsed, but I cannot find any suggestions for passing it through Flask. I am not sure it is wholly the data format....but everything else looks right.

Comment: try to print `raw` after `json.loads`

Comment: The data is above and also the date_time value in the second dictionary after the parsing. It is doing its job, but somehow the format angers python. I think it is something about what the dictionary expects.

Comment: Maybe some items in data don't have `date_time` key?

Comment: They all have it...I pull them off of the USGS website using the date time field. If it were missing I would not get the date out. But I will double check this entry to see if it is all there!